# Cannot use parallel on a char array?

Tags: d

I have tried this both on the online tour of D and with ldc locally. This Error puzzles me.
What is so special about char compared to int so that it cannot be made a ref from parallel?

```
import std.stdio : writeln;
import std.parallelism;

void main()
{
    auto arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8];
    foreach(ref i; parallel(arr)) {
        //writeln(typeid(i));
        i = i*i;
    }
    
    writeln(arr);
    
    auto result = [ 'w','e','l','c','o','m','e','t','o','d'];
    //foreach( ref c; parallel(result)) --> Error: foreach: cannot make c ref
    foreach( ref c; result)
    {
        //writeln(typeid(c));
        c = 'a';
    }
    writeln(result);
    
    writeln(typeid(arr));
    writeln(typeid(result));
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`char` is somewhat of a partial type - it represents a piece of a unicode character, not a whole character. Consider the Chinese character 维 - its representation in memory is `E7 BB B4`, or an array of three `char`s. Because of this, D does not let you operate on `char` the same way you would other types.

D does not have a separate type for ASCII text, so if you want to treat a string as ASCII, you should use `ubyte[]` instead of `char[]`.

Answer (score 3):

By default Phobos treats char arrays as bidirectional ranges of dchar. To override that use std.utf.byCodeUnit. https://dlang.org/library/std/utf/by_code_unit.html

Comment: Humm so this prevent the spliting at given position in parallel. This is why normal foreach works but not parallel?

Comment: This does not prevent the splitting of a code-point, you could potentially split multi-unit code points between different threads. However foreach is a language feature. The language considers char arrays to be arrays with slicing and indexing. Phobos does not rely on the language for this, but instead has its own view of what a char array is. e.g. `hasLength!(string) == false`, but `"hello".length == 5`. It's known as the autodecoding problem, and it's kind of a mess in D.